# Basic CRUD Application Using PHP, Prototype.js and Scriptaculous.js

Tags: php, javascript

I want to develop a web application using PHP and JavaScript.

There should be functionality of validations, data searching (from tables), sorting and pagination.

But my application should be built upon PHP, `prototype.js` and `scriptaculos.js`. I don't want to use jQuery and similar tools due to virus issues.

Is there any tutorial on `prototype.js` and `scriptaculos.js`? Please guide me.

Comment: JQuery - gives you virus issues.

Comment: What do you mean by virus issues with jQuery? If there is a chance of getting a virus via jQuery, then the chances of that happening with other JS frameworks is equally same.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could try the [Prototype documentation](http://www.prototypejs.org/learn) and the [Scriptaculous documentation](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous).

Out of curiousity, what sort of virus issues could you be having with jQuery?  It's a simple Javascript library.  You can even just use the one hosted at Google... how could you possibly get a virus from it that way?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the google hosted jquery if you affraid.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/ 
libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this referring to jQuery being detected as a virus by certain anti-virus programs as I think I remember hearing this a while back but as I remember it was due to people incorrectly serving JavaScript with improper mime-types. If this is what you are referring to then you really shouldn't worry about this.

Might also be worth checking out the book mentioned on Thomas Fuchs'(creator of Scriptaculous) blog here http://mir.aculo.us/2009/06/09/new-book-on-using-scripty-with-php/